# How to pack two values of shape (?, 2) and (?, 3) in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pack

I'm trying to use tf.pack on two values that have shape (?, 2) and (?, 3) by axis=0, but I get the error that they're incompatible. Is there a way for me to stack the values by columns so I have a value of shape (?, 5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tf.concat()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#concat) for this.

```
a = tf.placeholder('float', (None, 2))
b = tf.placeholder('float', (None, 3))
c = tf.concat(1, [a,b])
```